# implement push notification in firebase with batch

Tags: firebase, mbaas

I am trying to make  `firebase` and `batch` work together so that I can fire push notification when something in `firebase` db got changed. I followed this [tutorial](https://batch.com/parse-replacement-with-firebase)  and now i want to make them work automatically and for that i contacted with `batch`'s and they replied me

> write your own server-side code to 1. detect Firebase db changes 2. call the Batch API.

For  "detect Firebase db changes" I have to create a server-side code  which will track changes and call `batch`'s `api` accordingly. [Then follow this documentation](https://dashboard.batch.com/doc/api/transactional.html) for attaching the changed content and send it to appropriate user.

I don't know how to create the server side code. Anyone can give me a quick instructions on it or there's any tutorial related to this?

Answer (score 1):

To write server-side Firebase code you can use the node.js SDK. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html (search the page for node.js).

The API is exactly the same as the regular web API except that you'll be writing it as a node.js application that can be run on the server. You can then integrate this with Batch's API.

Comment: hey man thanks a lot for your quick response , let me check your link :)